# Law of total probability?

Tags: probability

Could you help me on this question. 
In a box, there are same numbers of two kinds of coins: 
the fair coins (50% chance for head) and the biased coins (70% chance for head). 
One person randomly selected a coin and tosses it twice. Both tosses are tails. What is the probability that the selected coin is a biased coin?

Comment: hmm may improve your problem typing. Just use "law of total probability"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We define 
$T_i=$the event that the $i^{th}$ toss results in a tail 
$H_i=$the event that the $i^{th}$ toss results in a head 
$B_i=$the event that the selected coin is biased 
$F_i=$the event that the selected coin is fair

Hence the required probability $=P(B|T_1 \cap T_2)$ 
$$=\large\frac{P(B)\cdot P(T_1 \cap T_2|B)}{P(B)\cdot P(T_1 \cap T_2|B)+P(F)\cdot P(T_1 \cap T_2|F)}$$ 
$$=\large\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\frac{3}{10})^2}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\frac{3}{10})^2+\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2}$$ 
$$=\large\frac{\frac{9}{100}}{\frac{9}{100}+\frac{1}{4}}$$ 
$$=\frac{9}{34}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are great. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: You're welcome.